# Why is this udev rule blocking?

Tags: 13.04, udev, xinput

Here is a rule from my `/lib/udev/rules.d` directory:

`SUBSYSTEM=="input", ATTRS{idVendor}=="045e", ATTRS{idProduct}=="008c", RUN+="/home/mikeknoop/scripts/udev-receiver.sh"`

Here is the simple contents of the `udev-receiver.sh` script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "UDEV-RECEIVER INIT" >> /var/log/external.log

{
sleep 5;
echo "Done" >> /var/log/external.log
} &

echo "UDEV-RECEIVER FINISH" >> /var/log/external.log
```

When I plug in my device, the output of `external.log` is as you would expect:

```
UDEV-RECEIVER INIT
UDEV-RECEIVER FINISH
Done
```

However, I am also tailing the syslog `/var/log/syslog` and can see that even though I have forked the long-running `sleep` process, `udev` device initialization is blocking until after `Done` shows up in my `external.log` file.

The reason this is important is because I am trying to set some device properties via `xinput` but the device isn't listed via `xinput list` until the entire `udev` initialization is completed (until after `Done` shows up in `external.log`).

According to the [udev(7) - Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/7/udev%3a)

> "Add a program to the list of programs to be executed for a specific
>   device. This can only be used for very short running tasks. Running an
>   event process for a long period of time may block all further events
>   for this or a dependent device. Long running tasks need to be
>   immediately detached from the event process itself."

I am unable to reconcile the man page and the behavior that I am seeing. Can anyone shed light or offer a better way to set properties via `xinput` when a device is inserted?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Answering my own question after lots of further research.

## The new udev "philosophy"

Apparently the new "proper" way to use `udev` is not to incur long-running processes.

Via http://blog.fraggod.net/2012/06/16/proper-ish-way-to-start-long-running-systemd-service-on-udev-event-device-hotplug.html:

> RUN ... Starting daemons or other long running processes is not
>   appropriate for udev; the forked processes, detached or not, will be
>   unconditionally killed after the event handling has finished.

Note how this is in contradiction to the man-page citation in OP.

My best guess is a recent `udev` change (~2012 sometime) forces all processes **including** their forked children to finish before allowing execution to continue as an enforcement mechanism for this new philosophy.

Therefore, all easily accessible documentation and answers on the web which give the pattern in OP as a solution are now broken.

The new long-running pattern philosophy is understandable in the instance when you're talking about some daemon that is always running when the device is plugged in. However, is obliterates the effective `defer` use-case along with it.

## Workaround

Nonetheless, I also discovered a workaround:

#### `/lib/udev/rules.d/98-mouse-config.rules/`

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="045e", ATTRS{idProduct}=="008c", ACTION=="add|remove", ENV{ID_TYPE}!="hid", RUN+="/home/mikeknoop/scripts/udev-receiver.sh"
```

#### `udev-receiver.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo /home/mikeknoop/scripts/mouse.sh | at now
```

#### `mouse.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 3;
export DISPLAY=":0.0"
export XAUTHORITY="/home/mikeknoop/.Xauthority"
/usr/bin/xinput --set-prop 'pointer:Microsoft Microsoft Wireless Optical Mouse® 1.0A' 'Device Accel Constant Deceleration' 2.00000
... more xinput rules here
```

**Note** This was tested and works on Ubuntu 13.04

**Note** You'll need to install `at` which is an async task package via `sudo apt-get install at`

I pieced together the workaround from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28548/how-to-run-custom-scripts-upon-usb-device-plug-in

Comment: While this is probably working, it is a long path around. There is a better direct way using xorg.conf . see https://askubuntu.com/q/1150247/26246